# How should second differentials and differentials of one-forms be expressed?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, vector-fields

Components with under-barred indices are expressed on a covariantly constant basis.  This is equivalent saying the under-barred coordinates lie in the tangent plane.  Basis vectors are written in the form used in the context of differential forms (partial derivative operators and basis one-forms), as well as in the traditional contragredient form.  The components of the covariant basis vectors, $\mathfrak{e}_\alpha$ are written as the components of the differential  mapping, transformation curvilinear coordinates to tangent plane coordinates.

This means that $\mathit{e}^{\underline{\alpha }}{}_{\alpha }=\delta^{\underline{\alpha }}{}_{\alpha }$ at the point of tangency; but do not have vanishing derivatives.  The components of the contravariant basis vectors are the components of the inverse differential transformation.  The affine connection coefficients $\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\alpha\delta}$ are defined in terms of the differentials of the covariant basis vectors.  The contractions

$$\delta ^{\alpha }{}_{\beta }=d\mathit{x}^{\alpha }\left[\mathfrak{e}_{\beta }\right],$$

are invariant.

The purpose of the derivation is to show how to express the differentials of the contravariant basis vectors (basis one-forms) in terms of the connection coefficients (blue text). I simply strong-armed the differential forms notation to comply with the method of derivation I am already familiar with.

**My question is: how should this notation be used, and interpreted?**

In particular, are these the correct forms of the intended values

$$d\mathfrak{e}^{\alpha}\cdot\mathfrak{e}_{\beta}
=dd\mathit{x}^{\alpha}\left[\mathfrak{e}_{\beta}\right]
=d\mathit{x}^{\alpha}{}_{,\delta}\left[\mathfrak{e}_{\beta}\right]d\mathit{x}^{\delta},$$

based on the contravariant vector notation?

The expression $d\mathit{x}^{\alpha}{}_{,\delta}$ seems problematic, since it appears to be the differential of the identity transformation $\frac{\partial\mathit{x}^{\alpha}}{\partial{x}^{\delta}}=\delta ^{\alpha }{}_{\beta }.$  Given the context, that is not what this should mean.

Finally, the expression

$$dd\mathit{x}^{\alpha }=-\Gamma ^{\alpha }_{\sigma \delta }d\mathit{x}^{\delta } d\mathit{x}^{\sigma }$$

is correct in standard calculus, but might mean the exterior derivative in the context of differential forms.

[image]

Comment: Notation should be prescribed, not interpreted. If there is a "usual suspects" sort of notation then it should be used. If not, then specify one and be consistent.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the usual suspects.   I want to know how the exterior calculus sectarians interpret the language of tensor calculus in their arcana.   See the final paragraph on page 78 https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43006/43006-pdf.pdf